# Dynamically generating injections by annotation

Tags: guice

Suppose I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Inject
    public MyClass(@Foo("whatever") Bar dependency) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And I wanted to have some custom logic that can see we're injecting an object of type `Bar` with an annotation of type `@Foo("whatever")` and construct a corresponding Bar object...something like a Guice `Provider`, but that gets more context information about the injection site. Does Guice let me do something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing isn't possible through normal Guice: Providers are intended to be zero-argument pure functions and there's no way to plumb the injection site information into them as you would a flexible callback function.

You can approximate what you want, though, two different ways:

- If you know *every single* possible value of `@Foo`'s parameter, you can make your `@Foo` a [binding annotation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations) and bind it by providing a [Annotation-compatible `equals` and `hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html). This provides the most intuitive experience: You can do anything with your `@Foo` you can do with any other type, such as using `@Foo` in constructors or injecting `@Foo("value") Provider<Bar> barProvider`.

  ```
  @Override public void configure() {
    for (String value : PREDEFINED_VALUES) {
      bind(Bar.class)
          .annotatedWith(new FooImpl(value))
          .toProvider(new BarProvider(value));
    }
  }
  ```
- If you want `@Foo` to work for arbitrary parameters, you'll need to extend Guice with [custom injections](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomInjections). This won't work for constructor injection or alongside any other `@Inject` annotations, but it will allow you to inspect types after Guice injection is finished to augment them as you see fit (e.g. detecting and reacting to `@Foo` annotations on fields).

  See [the example in the Guice docs](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomInjections) for more information there.

Internally, Guice's core is effectively a `Map<Key, Provider>`, where a Key represents a pair of a possibly-parameterized type and an optional binding annotation. The former binding annotation trick works because Guice can map your injection request to a Provider all on its own, where the latter skips Guice's map so you can inspect/construct/inject instances all on your own.

---

If you're willing to skip the annotation part of your solution, you could inject a `BarProvider` or `BarFactory` that exposes a `forFoo(String)` method, which would give you consistent injection without knowing all your String values ahead of time. This would allow you to use [assisted injection](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject) or [AutoFactory](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/factory) to generate your factory (if you want to generate one instance per call), or let you write a straightforward factory yourself for added flexibility.

```
public class MyClass {
    private final Bar dependency;

    @Inject
    public MyClass(BarProvider barProvider) {
        dependency = barProvider.forFoo("whatever");
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I was afraid this would be the answer :) The first way isn't applicable because I *don't* know every possible value in advance, and the second way is suboptimal because it requires having non-final fields on the class...ah well. Thanks for the thorough response.

Comment: @Max: The lack of options is partly because you want to do this with annotations. You could easily just inject a BarProvider that exposes `barProvider.forFoo(value)`, which I would favor here. (Will edit in later.)