# Guice JIT annotated binding

Tags: java, guice

Imagine the following annotation and type:

```
@interface MyAnnotation {
    String value();
}

class MyType {}

class MyOtherType {}
```

I use Guice constructor injection to inject the following:

```
class MyServer {

    @Inject
    MyServer(@MyAnnotation("some value") MyType myType) {

    }
}
```

When Guice evaluates the binding, I'd like it to call my factory:

```
class MyAnnotationFactory {

    @Inject
    private MyOtherType myOtherType;

    MyType get(MyAnnotation annotation) {
        // return a particular MyType based on the annotation
        return myOtherType.getMyType(annotation.value());
    }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this in Guice?

Comment: not sure, but will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226912/guice-how-to-implement-a-factory-that-returns-different-implementations

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't possible. Marking as a dupe of [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33087905/1426891), which goes into more detail, but I can reopen if your question is different. As the linked answer indicates, you'd be better off injecting `MyAnnotationFactory` directly, so you can call it to get your `MyType` as needed.